# Overlay using opencv using C++

Tags: c++, opencv

My question is about trying to fixing the italized line so that my overlay will work properly and instead of black pixels there are white pixels based  on my conditional statement.  I have tried several things such as using different types such as:

```
                out1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]=image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]; 
                out1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1]=image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1]; 
                out1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2]=image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
```

But I got a heap error.  I believe I am really close but I need some advice or guidance. Please excuse any errors that I have made posting for this is my first post.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
Mat image; // new blank image
Mat image2;
Mat out1;

image2 = cv::imread("test2.bmp",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); // read the file
image = cv::imread("test1.bmp",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);


if (!image.data) // error handling if file does not load
{
    cout<< "Image 1  not loaded";
    return -1;
}
if (!image2.data)
{
    cout << "Image 2 not loaded";
    return -1;
}

// resize images to make sure all images is the same size
cv::resize(image2, image2, image.size());
cv::resize(image2, out1, image.size());
// copying content of overlay image to output file
//image2.copyTo(out1);
out1 = image2.clone();
// for loop comparing pixels to original image
for (int i =0; i < out1.rows; i++)
{
        for(int j =0; j < out1.cols; j++)
        {
            //Vec3b color = image.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j));
            if(out1.at<uchar>(i,j)==0 && out1.at<uchar>(i,j) ==0 && 
            out1.at<uchar>(i,j)==0)
            {
                out1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]=255; // blue channel
                out1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1]=255; // green channel
                out1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2]=255; // red channel
            }
              else
               *out1.at<uchar>(i,j) = image.at<uchar>(i,j);*
        }
  }


  cv::imwrite("out1.bmp",out1);  // save to output file



    namedWindow("Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// creat a window to  
     display w/label
    imshow("Display window",out1); // show image inside display window

   waitKey(0);
   return 0;
}
```

My image is close to being overlayed correctly.  My issue is that the 
pixels shows up black instead of white due to a certain line in my 
program

[image]

Comment: You load grayscale images but try to work with Vec3b. The accessors need to operate on the datatype of your Mat, which in this case is uchar, not Vec3b.

Comment: Ok Thank you I will  try that.

Comment: I can not believe it was something so simple!  Thank you for the advice!